# Replacing the values of one column based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two `.csv` files.

'data.csv':

| ID | start_sec | end_sec | labels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| --PJHxphWEs | 30.000 | 40.000 | "/m/09x0r,/t/dd00088" |
| --ZhevVpy1s | 50.000 | 60.000 | "/m/012xff" |

'labels.csv'(There are like 500 labels in this file, but to show you what it looks like):

| index | labels | labels_en |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | /m/09x0r | "Speech" |
| 1 | /m/05zppz | "Male speech, man speaking" |

I want to take the labels in 'data.csv', compare them against the labels in 'labels.csv' then save the corresponding `labels_en` to a new column in my 'data.csv'.

As you can see, there can be more than one label that needs to be compared from 'data.csv' labels, but they are both within one string as shown by the first row of the table "/m/09x0r,/t/dd00088" -- that is two different values to find a corresponding labels_en for.

There is also some difficulty with labels not being encased in "", so the type of the data in 'data.csv' labels is a different type to the data in 'labels.csv' labels.

How do I go about doing this? I've tried a few different things in python but haven't been having any joy. Can anyone suggest how to do this? Or at least point me in the right direction.

The code I've tried so far:

```py
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.read_csv('labels.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')


merged_df = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='labels')

for index, row in merged_df.iterrows():
  labels = row['labels']
  string = row['labels_en']
  df2.loc[df2['labels'] == labels, 'labels'] = string

df2.to_csv('modified_csv.csv', index=False)
```

But I don't think it's even close yet, and the `pd.merge()` doesn't work because the types of labels are different.

Comment: if you share the code that you tried that would be better

Comment: I've added the code I've tried but I don't think it's anywhere near right

Comment: In "/m/09x0r,/t/dd00088" is ","(comma) the separating string?

Comment: Yes, the comma is separating the string. So "/m/09x0r" is one string to compare against the labels, and "t/dd00088" is another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem, the best way to replace `df1`'s `labels` with `df2`'s `labels` could be, by making `dictionary` of `df2`'s `labels` & `labels_en` column, and use them in replacing.
Here's the code to perform this:

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.read_csv('labels.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df=df2.drop(["index"],axis=1) # Removing unnecessary Column
di=dict(df.values) # {"/m/09x0r":"Speech",....}

def replace(x):
    r=[]
    for a in x.split(","):
        b=di.get(a)
        if b==None:
            r.append(a)
        else:
            r.append(b)
    return ",".join(r)

# Just replacing in same column
df1["labels"]=df1["labels"].apply(replace) # You may make new column
print(df1)


# Or same but one-liner solution is
df1["labels"]=df1["labels"].apply(lambda x:",".join([di.get(a) if di.get(a)!=None else a for a in x.split(",")]))

print(df1)


"""
Output: 
            ID  start_sec  end_sec             labels
0  --PJHxphWEs       30.0     40.0  Speech,/t/dd00088
1  --ZhevVpy1s       50.0     60.0          /m/012xff
"""
```

What we are doing here is, first importing both data.csv & labels.csv file. Making dictionary using `labels.csv` file. And replacing `labels` of `df1` which is separated by "," using dictionary.

Comment: Apologies for taking a moment to reply to this. I had a project to get finished before coming back to this. I appreciate the clear answer. However, I can't get this code to run. It seems pandas cant import via `read_csv()`. It says, `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 4, saw 6`. Can you help with this? It repeats this error for many different lines.

Comment: Line 5: `--aO5cdqSAg, 30.000, 40.000, "/t/dd00003,/t/dd00005"`

Comment: Is it interpreting the commas in the string as separate columns?

Comment: @rusty_vibess How about doing `pd.read_csv('labels.csv',delimiter=", ")`? `delimiter=", "` means we are separating column using ", ". If it isn't also working, then I probably have to look raw data of "data.csv" & "labels.csv". [edit] the question and add raw data as well...

Comment: I tried this, and at first, it didn't work. The compiler suggests adding `engine="python"` as an arg, this then gets it to run, but the data file has `""` added all over. Line 1 looks like this after using the delimiter `"--PJHxphWEs, 30.000, 40.000, ""/m/09x0r,/t/dd00088"""`

Comment: @rusty_vibess Okay, Can you please try `for a in x.replace('"',"").split(","):` in replace function.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I am now getting this error `script.py", line 21, in <module>
    df1["labels"]=df1["labels"].apply(replace) # You may make new column` `KeyError: 'labels'`

Comment: Here is all code that has been changed since your original answer: `df2 = pd.read_csv('labels.csv', delimiter=",", engine="python")` `df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=", ", engine="python")` and `for a in x.replace('"',"").split(","):`. Everything else is still the same. `df2` needed to have it's delimiter as `','` because there is no space in the comma separation of `labels.csv`. While the commas in `data.csv` did have a whitespace.

Comment: @rusty_vibess Can you please provide me, both of these files from any file sharing platform, if possible? I am not able to figure out, what is happening, there...

Comment: Sure, I have created a git repo and put everything in there. [Repo](https://github.com/rusty-vibess/python_csv)

Comment: In "data-25.csv" file titles there is not ", " but there is only ",". So, it isn't recognizing as header, but other then that, everything is fine. You don't need to have, both `.apply()` function you can have only one-liner or other. If you're using one-liner then don't forget to do `for a in x.replace('"',"").split(",")`.

Comment: Thank you very much! You've been a great help and I needed this for a university project. I've merged the pull request so the [repo](https://github.com/rusty-vibess/python_csv/tree/main/csv_dict) so it now has the working code. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Explode][1] your data_df

```
df_data = df_data.assign(labels2=df_data['labels'].str.split(',')).explode('labels2')
df_data
Out[279]: 
            ID  start_sec  end_sec               labels     labels2
0  --PJHxphWEs       30.0     40.0  /m/09x0r,/t/dd00088    /m/09x0r
0  --PJHxphWEs       30.0     40.0  /m/09x0r,/t/dd00088  /t/dd00088
1  --ZhevVpy1s       50.0     60.0            /m/012xff   /m/012xff
```

[Merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) it with df_labels and get labels_en

```
df_data['labels_en']=df_data.merge(df_labels,left_on='labels2',right_on='labels')['labels_en']
df_data[['ID','start_sec','end_sec','labels','labels_en']]
Out[284]: 
            ID  start_sec  end_sec               labels labels_en
0  --PJHxphWEs       30.0     40.0  /m/09x0r,/t/dd00088    Speech
0  --PJHxphWEs       30.0     40.0  /m/09x0r,/t/dd00088    Speech
1  --ZhevVpy1s       50.0     60.0            /m/012xff       NaN
```